# Copy a char vector to another vector

Tags: c++, vector, char

I'm trying to create a function to copy an vector into another one :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

int clone(std::vector <char> X, std::vector <char> Y){
    for(int i(0);i<X.size();i++){
        Y[i]=X[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I call the function, nothing appears on the prompt window.

Comment: where is `main` function? and u need vectors to be taken by reference (at least the copier). and u can copy a vector simply as `copy = original`

Comment: Probably more helpful if you show a bit more of your code. However, one thing that is clear is that your function takes its arguments **by value** - so *copies* of the two vectors will be sent, and those in the calling module will be unchanged.

Comment: Why not just have: `Y = X;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code. The first is that any modification to `Y` will not be visible at the call site, since you are passing the `vector` by value. Instead, you need to pass it by reference.

Second, you are indexing `X` incorrectly (assuming `X` is not as large as `Y`). Instead, you could just `push_back` the values.

However, you can even copy `vector`s directly, so you could do:

```
int clone(std::vector <char> const &X, std::vector <char> &Y){
    Y = X;
    return 0;
}
```

At this point, having a named function is rather pointless, since instead of doing something like:

```
std::vector<char> y;
clone(x, y);
```

you could simply do:

```
auto y = x;
```

which is much more readable.

Comment: I get everything except the last part. I need to copy my array x multiple times, how does the `auto y =x `works ?

Comment: It calls the copy constructor of the vector and creates `y` as a copy of `x`. You probably want to research some C++ basics like constructors, operator overloading, etc. - which exist to avoid you having to write code like that you were originally trying, by having classes handle it